# C++ linker undefined reference to function cannot find my error

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-reference

It is a homework problem.  It compiles fine, but linker gives undefined reference to my function getSalesData - line 20 just after my first for loop.  Here is the code.  I cannot find where I have done anything incorrectly; I have my prototype defined and it matches my function header, and I am simply calling the function.

```
// chips and salsa
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int getJarsSold(std::string type);
void getSalesData(int jarsSold[],int size,int &totalJars,int &highSeller,int &lowSeller);

int main() {
   const int SIZE = 5;
   const std::string salsaTypes[] {"Mild","Medium","Sweet","Hot","Zesty"};
   int jarsSold[SIZE] = {};
   int highIndex,lowIndex,totalJarsSold;


   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      jarsSold[i] = getJarsSold(salsaTypes[i]);
   }

   getSalesData(jarsSold,SIZE,totalJarsSold,highIndex,lowIndex);

   std::cout << "   Type     Jars Sold\n";
   std::cout << "---------------------\n";
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      std::cout << std::setw(8) << salsaTypes[i] << std::setw(15) << jarsSold[i] << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << "*********************\n";
   std::cout << "Total Sales = " << totalJarsSold << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Highest Seller = " << salsaTypes[highIndex] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Lowest Seller = " << salsaTypes[lowIndex] << std::endl;
}

int getJarsSold(std::string type) {
   bool validData = false;
   int numJars;

   while (!validData) {
      std::cout << "Enter jars sold this month for " << type << " salsa type: ";
      std::cin >> numJars;

      if (numJars < 0) {
         std::cout << "Number of jars sold must be 0 or positive number.\n";
      }
      else {
         validData = true;
      }
   }
   validData = false;

   return numJars;
}

void getSalesData(int jarsSold[],int size,int totalJars,int highIndex,int lowIndex) {
   bool firstRun = true;
   int highVal,lowVal;
   totalJars = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if (firstRun) {
         highIndex = i;
         highVal = jarsSold[highIndex];
         lowIndex = i;
         lowVal = jarsSold[lowIndex];
         totalJars += jarsSold[i];
         firstRun = false;
      }
      else {
         totalJars += jarsSold[i];
         if (jarsSold[i] > highVal) {
            highVal = jarsSold[i];
            highIndex = i;
         }
         if (jarsSold[i] < lowVal) {
            lowVal = jarsSold[i];
            lowIndex = i;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  I am just using -c for compiling and -o for linking, nothing fancy as I know no better.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: chips_and_salsa.o: in function `main':
chips_and_salsa.cpp:(.text+0x225): undefined reference to `getSalesData(int*, int, int&, int&, int&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The declaration signature in the beginning does not match the signature in the definition (`int &totalJars` vs `int totalJars` and so on), so they are treated as different functions.

Comment: Ok.  So the reference symbol must go in the header as well.  Thanks, I was completely overlooking that.

Comment: @WilliamS Yes. The function declaration and definition have to match exactly including reference symbols. Otherwise the linker will complain with undefined reference errors.

Comment: Note that the meaning of `int` and `int&` is different; the former is called an "in" parameter and the latter an "in/out" parameter. You should use it only when the function is supposed to modify the passed-in variable. In/out parameters are sometimes considered bad style. Consider using a return value of a function instead.